# Less.php parse and overwrite variable

Tags: php, css, less

Is it possible to overwrite an existing varibale via a sent parameter?

Example:
My CSS

```
/* ... */
@bg_color: purple;
@h_color: lighten(@bg_color,25);
#header { background: @bg_color; }
/* ... */
```

Now when I call:

```
$less->parse(array('bg_color' => 'blue'));
```

it has no effect. The variable will not be overwritten.
The idea is to use the variable in the CSS as a "Fallback-Color"

Any ideas how I can force less.php to overwrite existing variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:
less.php canot overwrite less-variables!

Answer (score 1):

I think you calling the `parse()` method wrong, the current signature of [git-master](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/blob/master/lessc.inc.php#L1339) is:

```
function parse($str = null, $initialVariables = null) {
```

It's since the 3.x.x version, [prior to that](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/blob/b6f73f47de77494aaf2f02e040dfe2f0bb8c1081/lessc.inc.php#L1198) (2.0.0 tag) it had only the `$str` parameter, (actual change commit of that line is [here](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/commit/018d5dfea2aeef0adf403086ddfc5e6c2fd7b5d9)).

As for overwriting: The way lessc parses your code is that it pushes the variables you give them in phpland and then reads the source less file. The source less file will always take precedence because of that, you can't load a less file for compilation and change variables in them within them before `lessc` generates output.